# How to view branches and tags in git log of a file?

Tags: git, logging

I can get a pretty commit history graph of a Git repo::

```
git log --all --graph --decorate
```

This shows the branches and tags, if any, that are associated with every commit.

Similarly, I can view the commit history graph of any file in the repo:

```
git log --all --graph --decorate foobar.cpp
```

But this does not show the branches and tags attached to each commit.

Is there a way to display branches and tags in the git log of a file?

Here is a simple repo with 3 commits, 2 branches (`master` and `feature1`). `readme1.txt` is modified in all 3 commits. `readme2.txt` was added in first commit and untouched after that.

git log of the repo shows the branch names and `HEAD`:

[image]

git log of `readme1.txt` shows the branch names and `HEAD`:

[image]

However, git log of `readme2.txt` shows neither branch names nor the `HEAD`:

[image]

The one commit of this `readme2.txt` should have both the branch names and `HEAD` too. That is because if I checkout `master` or `feature1` branch, I would get this commit of `readme2.txt`. In a real world repo, you can imagine how this might be useful, to know which branches a commit of a file belongs to.

How to get git log to display those branch names for this file?

Comment: If a commit in the result of `git log --all --graph --decorate foobar.cpp` happens to be pointed to by a branch or a tag, the branch and the tag will be displayed along with the commit.

Comment: @ElpieKay I have added screenshots showing what I would like git log to display. I cannot find any option that does this in git log.

Comment: because no branch or tag points to the commit `a176532`, though this commit is reachable from `HEAD`, `feature1` and `master`. You could run `git branch foo a176532` and `git tag bar a176532` and then have another git-log try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `--source --branches`, but there is a problem here.

As [ElpieKay noted in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44459556/how-to-view-branches-and-tags-in-git-log-of-a-file#comment75918142_44459556), the problem here is that the branch or tag does not point *directly to* the located commit.  It's worth remembering here that Git's branch and tag names act as pointers, pointing into an immutable graph that itself contains pointers.  That is, first we have the graph itself:

```
<--o  <--o  <--o  <--o
   ^           ^
    \           \
     o  <--o  <--o
```

where each `o` is a commit node and each arrow is a one-way arc connecting that node to some predecessor node(s).  (The lowest, right-most node here has two outgoing arcs, so it is a *merge commit*.)

On top of that graph, we add some external arrows leading to some node(s), which we call either *branches* or *tags*.  A branch name is meant to be a mutable (changeable) pointer, while a tag name is meant to be immutable:

```
 v1.0
   |
   v
<--o  <--o  <--o  <--o   <--develop
   ^           ^
    \           \
     o  <--o  <--o   <--master
```

The `--decorate` option tells `git log` that, when it prints the hash ID of one of the nodes in the graph, *if* that node has some of these "external arrows" pointing to it, `git log` should print their names (in parentheses, separated by commas).

When you use a file name argument, you tell `git log`: *print only those commit nodes where the diff between the parent of that commit and that commit itself says that the file is modified*.  (You also turn on what Git calls *history simplification*, which is important later.)  By suppressing the printout of commit nodes that have these external arrows, you suppress the decorations as well.

Git does offer the `--source` option to `git log`, but it's a bit limited.  What `--source` does is modify the graph-walk algorithm so that for each initially-visited commit node, it remembers which command-line branch or tag argument brought in this particular node.  This may be `HEAD`, or a branch or tag name, possibly derived from `--branches` or `--all` or similar arguments.  Then, as it works through its queue—because merges cause "walk forks", the revision walk code puts each graph node into a queue and walks through this queue in some order, determined by any topological sorting options you specified—Git copies this same source annotation into each visited node.

Suppose we give uppercase letter names names to each node in the above graph:

```
 v1.0
   |
   v
<--A  <--B  <--C  <--G   <--develop
   ^           ^
    \           \
     D  <--E  <--F   <--master
```

Now suppose you use `--decorate --source --branches --tags` (or `--decorate --source --all`), so that Git starts from nodes `A`, `G`, and `F` "simultaneously".

Node `A` is reached from the tag `v1.0`, so its `--source` is `v1.0`.  Node `G` is reached from the branch name `develop`, so its `--source` is `develop`.  Node `F` is reached from the branch name `master`, so its `--source` is `master`.  Now we begin the graph walk.

Which node is visited first?  That's difficult to say.  In fact, Git uses whichever node has the highest *commit time stamp*.  (If there is a tie, Git uses any of these nodes arbitrarily.)  We cannot see the commit time stamps here, but let's say highest one is in commit `G`: we'll visit that one first.  (Note that even if you make these commits on one computer yourself, in order, you can force any time stamp you like into any commit.  If people make the commits on different computers with different clocks, the time stamps may be all over the map.)

Printing out node `G`, we will see the `--source` of `develop` and the decoration `(develop)`.  This inserts node `C` into the queue, with `G`'s source, i.e., `develop`.

If we visit `F` first, instead of `G` first, we'll print it with a `--source` of `master` and a decoration `(master)`.  This will insert node `C` into the queue, with `F`'s source, i.e., `master`!

In short, there are *two* ways for us to reach nodes `C` and `B`: via `develop` or via `master`.  When we use `git log --source` we will see *one* of these two, but we don't necessarily know *which one*.  The limitation is that there is only one `--source` attribution.  Whatever source is attached to `C`, though, that same source will be attached to `B`.  (Meanwhile nodes `E` and `D` can only acquire `master` as their sources.)

There are *three* ways to reach node `A`, because of the tag; but we'll see `v1.0` as its `--source` as that label went into `git log`'s data structures the moment node `A` went into the queue.  (These `--source` annotations exist only during the `git log` run: they are never written back into the repository.)  If the walk proceeds to visit nodes before `A`, they will copy this `v1.0` as their source.

*Note that nodes enter the graph walk list only once.*  The initial list of nodes is formed from the command line arguments (or using `HEAD` if you gave no starting points).  After that, visiting a node inserts all its children unless those children have already been visited.  Whenever the list has more than one node in it, the next node to visit is controlled by whether you used the `--author-date-order`, `--date-order`, or `--topo-order` options.